Bibliography as section in the amsbook class
I am currently writing a document using the amsbook document class. The bibliography is put directly into the file using \begin{thebibliography}, and I want this bibliography to be a section. However, amsbook always makes the bibliography a chapter.
MWE:
\documentclass{amsbook}
\begin{document}

Citation \cite{A}

\begin{thebibliography}{A}

\bibitem[A]{A}
A.\ Author, \emph{Foobar}, J.\ Ournal \textbf{1} (1999).

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}

This produces a  file with three pages, the bibliography appearing on the last one as a new chapter (since there is a \cleardoublepage before each chapter).
What I would like to have is that the bibliography appears as a section right after the main text.
The following was suggested in several threads posing the analogous question for the book and report classes, it does not work (i.e., the output is exactly the same as in the above MWE):
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\chapter*}{\section*}{}{}
\begin{document}

Citation \cite{A}

\begin{thebibliography}{A}

\bibitem[A]{A}
A.\ Author, \emph{Foobar}, J.\ Ournal \textbf{1} (1999).

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}

Also the chapterbib package doesn't do anything: The output of the following is still exactly the same as in the MWE:
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\begin{document}

Citation \cite{A}

\begin{thebibliography}{A}

\bibitem[A]{A}
A.\ Author, \emph{Foobar}, J.\ Ournal \textbf{1} (1999).

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}

Q: How to turn the bibliography into a section in the amsbook class?
Since the document is long and complicated, I can't simply switch to the book class, this produces a ton of errors...

Without MWEB but only two lines of code, I cannot tell you much more than: chapterbib provides and option sectionbib. Currently it is also unclear, what you mean with: “the chapterbib package doesn't do anything”. So please help us helping you: Add a minimal working example with bibliography to your question and also clarify it, i.e.: How do you use chapterbib? How do you run BibTeX? What happens? What do you expect?

@cabohah: Thanks for these suggestions, I improved the question accordingly. I also added what I meant by chapterbib not doing anything.

You could redefine \@bibtitlestyle to replace \chapter with \section:
\documentclass{amsbook}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@bibtitlestyle}{%
  \@xp\section\@xp*\@xp{\bibname}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

Citation \cite{A}

\begin{thebibliography}{A}

\bibitem[A]{A}
A.\ Author, \emph{Foobar}, J.\ Ournal \textbf{1} (1999).

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}


Thanks a lot, works like a charm!

@BK You're welcome!
